# Python and Pandas - Convert Tue Jun 23 2020 to yyyy-mn-dd

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame (from a MongoDB database) that has a problemDate filed with a string using this format:

```
'Tue Jun 23 2020 13:40:56 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
```

For further processing, I need this to be in the yyyy-mm-dd format. I tried using DateTime but get an error:

```
yes_no_db['problemDate'] = pd.to_datetime(yes_no_db['problemDate'])
```

Gives me this error:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Tue Jun 23 2020 13:40:56 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)')
```

Wondering what I could do to convert the dates?

Thanks!

Comment: [`strftime` and `strptime` format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Adding to Chester, you will have to manipulate the strings to get down to a format from the above link that is available. For starters, you probably have to remove " (Coordinated Universal Time)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data contains more information than needed to parse date. Some cannot be understood by pandas, e.g. `Coordinated Universal Time` part. Let's try trimming a bit, then convert:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.problemDate.str.extract('^\w* ([\w]+ \d+ \d+)')[0])
```

Another option is to just clip the `(...)` part:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.problemDate.str.extract('^(.+) \(')[0])
```

Output:

```
0   2020-06-23
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

From there, if you want string format you can do:

```
s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and you get:

```
0    2020-06-23
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

which looks the same but actually has different data type (string this time)

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be converted in this raw format u need to slice it before u want to apply to_datetime function on it like the example below.

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'dates':  ['02-Sep-2019','13-Sep-2019','21-Sep-2019'],
      'status': ['Opened','Opened','Closed']
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['dates','status'])

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%m-%Y')#format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S for time

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

u need to format data into some definite type by which u can pass the format as an aurgument to the function for more info visit this link [`pd.to_datetime`](https://datatofish.com/strings-to-datetime-pandas/)